# libopen-rte.so.7 not found

Tags: libraries, mpi

I am trying to use openmpi. While i run, i face that output:

```
mpirun: error while loading shared libraries: libopen-rte.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In this site, someone has asked before a similar question for libopen-rte.so.12. From answers, i tried this command and i got these output

```
$ find /usr/lib/ -name *libopen-rte*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-rte.so.20.10.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so.20.10.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-rte.so.20
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-rte.so
```

So i cannot see libopen-rte.so.7 library in this list. What should i do?

Thank you your helping in advance

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you add more details, Ubuntu release ? I expect you have an old binary that you are trying to run?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Openmpi 1.8.7

Comment: In cases like this it is usually safe to create a symbolic link called `libopen-rte.so.7` to an existing file, usually the one without the index at the end, e.g. `libopen-rte.so`. In fact you have such a file. So you could try `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/libopen-rte.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/libopen-rte.so.7`.  That might work. However, you have many other candidates. Do they have roughly the same size and creation date?

Comment: @jos Still does not work. What do you mean by candidates?

Comment: @himungan From where did you get the openmpi package? does it have to be that vesrion exactly? Ubuntu provides a newer version.

Comment: I meant that instead of linking to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/libopen-rte.so` you could try one of the others in your list.

Comment: "Still does not work" - but the error message must have gone away now that you provided a link called `libopen-rte.so.7`. What does not work?

Comment: @user.dz I am junior cfd engineer. Openmpi exists in installation cfd software. It usese Openmpi 1.8.7. I saw the latest version of openmpi. But newer version does not work with cfd software stable

Comment: @himungan Would you please edit the question and move comment with important info up there, it will be easier for others to follow up, attract for users, comments also get removed sometimes. I have picked up few old packages that are still in repository, there is a gap between `.4` to `.12`, Even building from source is with low chance to to find all build dependencies that correspond to that version. http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openmpi/ & http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openmpi/

Comment: @himungan In case you want to follow dependencies check https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libopen-rte.so.7 ,that version only available in RPM, I expect your tool is build in an RPM based distribution.